# jquery form submit need twice click-submit for send

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a form but I have to click the button twice for it to submit. My code is:

```
<script>
    function processorform(id)
    {   
        jQuery('.sp-poll-'+id+' form').submit(formProcess);

        function formProcess(e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var poll = id;
            answer  = $('input[name=answer]:checked').val(),
            div     = $(this).parent(),
            action  = $(this).attr('action');

            $(this).show();
            updatePoll(action, poll, answer);
            $("#poll-"+id).hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

**The form:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $postFile;?>" class="format" id="spe_form-<?php echo $pollid; ?>" onsubmit="processorform('<?php echo $pollid; ?>');return false;">
    <input type="hidden" name="poll" value="<?php echo $pollid; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="backurl" value="<?php echo $thisPage; ?>"/>
</form>
```

Everything works fine except for having to click submit twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first click of submit will call the inline submit handler:

```
onsubmit="processorform('<?php echo $pollid; ?>');return false;"
```

Which calls `processorform()` and prevents the normal form submit due to the `return false;`.

The `processorform()` function, in turn, binds a submit handler via jQuery for what I assume is the same form (though you don't show the html for the element that contains the form):

```
jQuery('.sp-poll-'+id+' form').submit(formProcess);
```

So then on the next click, it will do the inline handler *again,* running the above function again, and the submit handler `formProcess()` bound from the previous click will now be executed.

I can only assume that your actual submit happens from the following line:

```
updatePoll(action, poll, answer);
```

...which calls a function that you didn't show.

I don't understand how the form is even being submitted given that it doesn't contain any visible fields or buttons, but anyway...

My guess at the simplest way to fix the click twice issue would be something like this:

```
function processorform(id) {
    var $form = jQuery('.sp-poll-' + id + ' form'),
        poll = id,
        answer = $('input[name=answer]:checked').val(),
        div = $form.parent(),
        action = $form.attr('action');

    $form.show();
    updatePoll(action, poll, answer);

    $("#poll-" + id).hide();
}
```

...though without knowing the things you didn't include in the question I can't be sure that it will work.

Comment: Tht´s funtion no improtant but this case the form submit works anyway if no put into , that´s function only for call other script and upload results into db , the problem it´s with processor and double click in submit , by other side i need use the function because i have more of one form and in each case each form have different id for submit , thank´´s for your help

Comment: Oh yeah nice now works perfectly , the best regards for your help i see th eproblem i have double function into other yeap , thank´s for the help

Comment: There's nothing wrong with nesting functions inside each other in a general sense. In your case that wasn't the problem per se, the problem was you were binding a second submit handler from inside the first.

Answer (score 0):

there might be syntax errors as well:

```
function processorform(id)
{   

jQuery('.sp-poll-'+id+' form').submit(formProcess);

// missing '}' ???

<script>  // this is already a script, why start a new script tag?

function formProcess(e) 
{
e.preventDefault();

var poll = id;

answer  = $('input[name=answer]:checked').val(),
div     = $(this).parent(),
action  = $(this).attr('action');



$(this).show();
updatePoll(action, poll, answer);

$("#poll-"+id).hide();


}

} // too many '}' ??
</script> // see above
```

The above code will "run"

- `<script>` will by almost ignored
- function in a function is fine

but from the crude syntax, the question is, whether it's actually doing what you intended?

Comment: The problem it´s when i push submit i need give 2 times for works , it´s the only problem

Comment: Yepp, that's what you programmed. See @nnnnnn's answer below, nothing to add.

Comment: Q: why are you binding a second submit handler here: `jQuery('.sp-poll-'+id+' form').submit(formProcess);`and overload the just running one?